# iPhone X Launch Screen Storyboard Align UITabBar to Bottom

Tags: storyboard, iphone-x, launch-screen

I am updating my LaunchScreen.storyboard for the iPhone X (using Xcode 9.1) but cannot get the UITabBar to align to the absolute bottom. The Bottom Layout Guide seems to end at the safe area using the suggested constraints. Does anyone know what property or constraint I need to add?

Note that I am deliberately using a UIViewController with a UITabBar instead of a UITabBarController because I do not want any tabs selected by default and this seems to be the only workaround.

[image: Xcode screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

If you uncheck "Safe Area Relative Margins" on the tab bar (shown in your screenshot), delete your existing bottom constraint, and then drag the `UITabBar` into the home indicator area... you should be able to create a new bottom constraint of "0" and it'll stay there.

We just ran into the same problem... and noticed that if you set the XIB to be for any device but the iPhone X it renders a pre-X sized `UITabBar` for those launch screens, so keep that in mind... leave it on that device setting if you run into the same issue.